# Angular 2 - Injectable Service need another Injectable Service - Uncaught Cannot resolve all parameters for

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

have problems with injecting service and Angular 2. When i launch app in chrome, i have the following error in console:

> reflective_provider.js:232  Uncaught Cannot resolve all parameters for
>   'User'(LocalDataBase, Platform, undefined). Make sure that all the
>   parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations
>   and that 'User' is decorated with Injectable.

The scenario is as follows:

My main App.ts call a service User.ts, and User.ts call 2 services:

```
App.ts
|
|--- Users.ts
     |
     |---localDataBase.ts
     |---DataServer.ts (service with http in constructor)
```

In my app.ts, i add:

```
providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS,LocalDataBase, SettingsSvc,DataServer,User]
```

Constructor in User.ts:

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {LocalDataBase} from './database';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {DataServer} from './dataServer';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class User {
constructor(private localDataBase: LocalDataBase,
    private platform: Platform,
    private dataServer: DataServer) {
```

Constructor in DataServer:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {AppSettings} from './appSettings';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import '../import/rxjs-operators';

@Injectable()
export class DataServer {
constructor(private http: Http) {
```

Someone have a clue? what's wrong?

I have added @Inject to all parameter without success.

Answer (score 0):

If you are injecting `DataServer` into the `app.ts` object, it will automatically be available to children of that object. Therefore, you do not need to inject it in `User.ts`

Comment: do you mean i have to remove "private dataServer: DataServer" from DataServer.ts constructor?